# How does WEKA calculate class probabilities?

Tags: java, weka

I saw some code snippets that shows how can weka produce the classification confidence. But my question is that how is that calculated?!

Answer (score 0):

Classification confidence is calculated by the particular classification algorithm you use, and different algorithms calculate it differently.

What is important to keep in mind in this matter, is that these values are more reliable for some algorithms and less reliable for others. What I mean by "Reliable" is that we want the algorithm to output smaller confidence values when the classification is less clear cut. So, for example, for misclassified examples we will prefer algorithms with smaller confidence values (at least they "warned" us that they were not sure) rather than algorithms with higher confidence values.

For Example, Random Forest algorithm produces quite reliable confidence values, while Decision Trees and Naive Bayes usually produce lass reliable values.